# Sender Name Differenet from Sender Address Oracle SMTP

Tags: email, smtp

I am writing a simple mailer program in oracle using SMTP.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                   p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                   p_subject   IN VARCHAR2,
                                   p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                   p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                   p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

While executing the program, the sender is automatically picked up as the first part from sender email address. E.g. If Sender mail is Dummy@zyz.com, the sender name appears as Dummy.

What I want to do is show the sender name as something while the mail address remains the same. E.g. For sender address Dummy@xyz.com, the sender name can be Test[anything other than Dummy].

Please guide how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change **only name of sender** via:

`UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_custom_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);`

That is, `p_custom_from = 'Test'` can be used to provide custom `Name` which may be different from what is specified in:

`UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);`